# Structuring a GAN in Tensorflow with python classes

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I am used to design my GANs in Keras. However for a specific need, I would like to adapt my code to Tensorflow. Most of the GANs implementation with Tensorflow use a class for the *GAN* and then a function for the *discriminator* and the *generator*

Which gives something that looks like this:

```
class MyGAN():
    def __init__(self):
        # various initialisation

    def generator(self, n_examples):
        ### do some business and return n_examples generated.

        return G_output

    def discrimintator(self, images):
        ### do some business with the images

        return D_Prob, D_logits
```

Which is, in fact perfectly fine. However, I much prefer the design where each part [MyGAN, Generator, Discriminator] is a complete and independant class. You initialise only the main one: *MyGAN* and it handles the rest by its own. It allows for me a much simpler code organisation and a relatively easier code reading.

However, I struggle on some design patterns, with **Keras** I can use the "Input" layer which allows me to switch from giving to the Discriminator real data from a dataset and fake data generated by the Generator. Just a few line to expose the idea with Keras *pseudo-code*:

```
class Generator(object):

    def __init__(self, latent_shape):

        gen_input = Input(shape=latent_shape, name='generator_input')

        #### ====== do some business ====== ####

        gen_output = Activation('tanh', name='generator_output')(previous_layer)

        self.model = Model(gen_input, gen_output)

class Discriminator(object):

    def __init__(self):

        disc_input = Input(shape=self.input_shape, name='discriminator_input')

        #### ====== do some business ====== ####

        disc_output = Activation('sigmoid', name='discriminator_output')(previous_layer)

        # Model definition with Functional API
        self.model = Model(disc_input, disc_output)

class MyGAN(object):

    def __init__(self):

        ########## GENERATOR ##########

        # We create the optimizer for G
        g_optim = Adam(lr=2e-4, beta_1=0.5)

        self.generator = Generator(latent_shape=(100,))        
        self.generator.model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=g_optim)

        ########## DISCRIMINATOR ##########

         We create the optimizer for D
        d_optim = Adam(lr=2e-4, beta_1=0.5)

        self.discriminator = Discriminator()
        self.discriminator.model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=d_optim, metrics=['accuracy'])

        ########## FULL GAN ##########

        # create an Input Layer for the complete GAN
        gan_input = Input(shape=self.latent_shape)

        # link the input of the GAN to the Generator
        G_output = self.generator.model(gan_input)

         For the combined model we will only train the generator => We do not want to backpropagate D while training G
        self.discriminator.model.trainable = False

        # we retrieve the output of the GAN
        gan_output = self.discriminator.model(G_output)

        # we construct a model out of it.
        self.fullgan_model = Model(gan_input, gan_output)
        self.fullgan_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=g_optim, metrics=['accuracy'])

    def train_step(self, batch):

        ## Train Generator First ##

        noise = #### Generate some noise with the size: 2*batch (D is trained twice)        
        loss, acc = self.fullgan_model.train_on_batch(noise, np.ones(noise.shape[0]))

        ## Train Discriminator Then ##

        self.discriminator.model.trainable = True

        generated_images = ### Generate samples with G with same size as batch

        d_loss_fake, d_acc_fake = self.discriminator.model.train_on_batch(
                generated_images,
                np.zeros(generated_images.shape[0])
            )
        d_loss_real, d_acc_real = self.discriminator.model.train_on_batch(
            X, 
            np.ones(X.shape[0])
        )

        d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake)
        d_acc  = 0.5 * np.add(d_acc_real,  d_acc_fake)

        self.discriminator.model.trainable = False
```

My Problem is quite simple, how can I **reproduce** such a code structure with Tensorflow ? I have a few ideas, but I'm not conviced with any of these:

I can use a **tf.Variable** and then use the *load* function to assign it during execution. The problem is: for each training step, it seems like I need to perform two *sess.run()* per network (D and G). Which is clearly inefficient...

- For the Generator:

  - 1: Generate Data with G with a `sess.run()` call
  - 2: Load the data in D with a `sess.run()` call
  - 3: Compute the loss with another `sess.run()` call
  - 4: Finally backpropagate G with a last `sess.run()`
- For the Discriminator:

  - 1: Generate Data with G with a `sess.run()` call
  - 2: Load the data in D with a `sess.run()` call
  - 3: Compute the loss for fake data with a `sess.run()` call
  - 4: Compute the loss for real data with a `sess.run()` call
  - 5: Finally backpropagate D with a last `sess.run()`

To me this just looks clearly inefficient and I have no better idea. I could of course use *placeholder* which would "hide" the load operation with with feed_dict but does not really impact the performances (I tried).

My objective is the following:

- Directly connecting G to D and be able to avoid calling G, just having G and D directly connected.
- Be able to "switch D" in getting data from G or from a data batch. This will allow me to avoid data transfer from the GPU/CPU => Saving time

Comment: Can't you connect the output of G to the first "layer" of D? It seems you can connect things freely as if they were tree branches. (And it seems that's exactly what keras does). You can run the last output and it will consider the entire net. Or you can run an intermediate output and it will consider the net only up to that point.

Comment: It is correct, however how can I design D to switch from G and Real Data whenever I want to ? The problem is not connecting G and D. It's about switching the entry point

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the design structure you want by using a purely functional approach and re-applying networks using variable scopes. For example, this code snippet sets up the real/fake part of the network:

```
with variable_scope.variable_scope(generator_scope) as gen_scope:
  generated_data = generator_fn(generator_inputs)
with variable_scope.variable_scope(discriminator_scope) as dis_scope:
  discriminator_gen_outputs = discriminator_fn(generated_data,
                                               generator_inputs)
with variable_scope.variable_scope(dis_scope, reuse=True):
  discriminator_real_outputs = discriminator_fn(real_data, generator_inputs)
```

Consider using [TensorFlow's TFGAN](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/gan) to avoid recreating the GAN infrastructure. [These examples](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/gan) demonstrate how to use TFGAN to create various kinds of GANs (using the , as well as using built-in features.